# How to convert float[] to object[] in c#?

Tags: c#

I hope converting (array of float to array of object) in c#.

So I was trying to convert like this.

```
Array.Copy(grossDataList.ToArray(), grossDataObjectArray, grossDataList.ToArray().Length);
```

But it didn't work.

Please Let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by didn't work?

Comment: It might have thrown an exception, not clear what u want to ask

Comment: that means, I can't convert float to object. there is any way converting?

Comment: `Array.Copy` works fine as far as I know. `var array1 = new float[]{1.1f, 1.2f, 1.3f}; var array2 = new object[3]; Array.Copy(array1, array2, 3); array2.Dump();` prints successfully these values as an `object`.

Comment: This code works fine for me. What is the error you get?

Answer (score 4):

As others mentioned, while you can cast a `float` to an `object` (the float will be [boxed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)), you can't cast a `float[]` to a `object[]`, since an `object[]` isn't a supertype of `float[]`.

The `Array.Copy` method described by others will work, but if you're using VS2008 or above, you can use the more expressive LINQ method:

```
float[] floats = new float[] { 0.1f, 0.2f};
object[] = floats.Cast<object>().ToArray();
```

The [`Cast<object>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension method will convert each `float` to an `object` and return an `IEnumerable<object>` with the results, which you can then convert to an array.

---

To understand exactly why a `float` can be cast to an `object` but a `float[]` can't be cast to an `object[]`, try reading up on **array covariance** (as Jeppe Stig Nielsen mentioned in the comments), though it's a relatively complicated topic (or, more commonly, complicatedly-*written* topic).

Simply put, a `float` can do anything an `object` can do (call `GetType` or `ToString`), but a `float[]` can't do whatever an `object[]` can (contain a `string` or an `int`, for instance), which is why they're not compatible.

Comment: Upvoted. More precisely you cannot cast a `float[]` to an `object[]` even when a `float` is an `object` for the reason that **array covariance** does not work with value types (`float` is a value type). At the same type **covariance in generics** (of `IEnumerable<out T>`) also does not work for value types, so for that reason you cannot copy to a new array with Linq `floats.ToArray<object>()` (which works for reference types).

Comment: As examples where covariance is allowed, try `string[] strArr = new string[] { "abc", null, "hello", };`. The element type `string` is a reference type (`class`). Then it is valid to say `object[] objArr1 = strArr;`. It creates a reference of another type to the same array instance. A bit dangerous, but allowed. At the same time you can write `object[] objArr2 = strArr.ToArray<object>();`. That copies the element references to a new array. It uses covariance of the generic type `IEnumerable<out T>` which is an interface that `T[]` implements, and which Linq extends (as in extension methods).

Answer (score 0):

Object array length must be shorter than the Float Array length in your case.

This works

```
float[] farr = { 45.356F, 78.0F, 35 };
        object[] oarr = new object[farr.Length];
        Array.Copy(farr, oarr, farr.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

A float[] is not an object[] and will never be. You can store the value "Hello" in the latter, but not in the former. Passing a float[] as an object[] would be unsafe.

Your only solution is to create a new object[] and fill it with the values from the original float[]. Use System.Array.Copy for this.

Answer (score 0):

From object to float:

```
 object[] ob = new object[] { 1.3f, 4.3f, 5.4f };
    float[] fl = ob.Cast<float>().ToArray();
```

From float to object:

```
 float[] fl = new float[] { 1.3f, 4.3f, 5.4f };
 object[] ob = ob.Cast<object>().ToArray();
```

When casting from object to float you have to be completely sure that the object array contains floats. Otherwise you'll get `InvalidCastException`. That is not mandatory if you cast `float` to `object` because anything can be represented as `object` in C#

Comment: Did the asker not want to convert in the opposite direction?